# Synchronous methods with Async block

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, synchronization

I have a question about synchronous working vs async.
For example we have this code:

```
[[WebClient shared] getSomeInfoWithParam:param handler:^(WebResponce *responce) {

    if (!responce.error)
    {
        [UI setUIWithDict:responce.dictionary];
    }
}];
```

I'm very interesting, what if wrap this code into background async ? Does it increase productivity or no ?

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    [[WebClient shared] getSomeInfoWithParam:param handler:^(WebResponce *responce) {

        if (!responce.error)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                [UI setUIWithDict:responce.dictionary];
            });
        }
    }];
    });
```

The most interesting moment, that it's anyway must be synchronous, so first i get info through block callback and then set ui, there is anyway some sort of UI blocking, is it right ?

Comment: Every UI operation should run on main, so you missed (I guess) [Hud Show] and dismiss hud. Other than that, if webclient is running network requests, you are right to run it on the background

Comment: what does it give me, running web request on the background ?

Comment: If the network request is synchronous, it doesn't block the current thread. If the request is asynchronous, there is no benefit.

Comment: I thought, that dispatch_sync waiting to return value

Comment: Thats right. I meant that if the request is synchronous and you wrap it with a dispatch_async it won't block the current thread.